# Binary search problem is not giving desired result. Not sure what is causing the issue?

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search

Here is my code:

Try to search a element from the list using age old binary search algo,

```
def binary_search(l, low, high, val):
    while low <= high:
        mid = (high + low) // 2
        #print(mid)
        if l[mid] > val:
            high = mid - 1
        elif l[mid] < val:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            return mid
    return -1
        


arr = [1,24,5,3]
result = binary_search(arr, 0,(len(arr)-1), 5)

if result == -1:
    print(" Not present")
else:
    print("given number present at index", result)
```

Output is: "Not present"

I am not able to get the issue where exactly it is missing to get the correct index, why is it not retuning the index = 2 for the given arr. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Binary search array should be sorted.

Try with arr = [1,3,5,24]

Comment: Thank you, I was in such a hurry to know the issue that I dint check the arr if its sorted or not! my bad . Yeah it works fine with sorted list. :-)